# Transferring StackOverflow experience points to Perlmonks

Tags: discussion, reputation, waffles

I'm thinking of cashing in my sweet and juicy StackOverflow reputation waffles into Perlmonks bagels.

Does anybody have a perl script to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'transferring' them?

Comment: Exchange rates between sites might be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking but maybe this will help

```
<iframe
  src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/127707.html?theme=clean"
  marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" 
  frameborder="0"  scrolling="no"
  width="210px" height="60px"
></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  However, you can go to [http://perlmonks.org/?node=thepen] and press the "Yes, I want to LOSE 5 XP!" button as many times as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

If an API is supplied for Stack Overflow in the future then it's fair to expect that you could access a user's experience points. I'd further expect that it'd only ever be read-only, for obvious reasons.